# Troubleshooting how to parse the part after the delimiter in C++?

Tags: c++, icalendar

just started learning C++ recently.
I am trying to read an ics file in the format:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:2179:203860:1:002:1:person
DTSTAMP:20170921T080000Z
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-ca:BIG CITY
LOCATION:CANADA
DTSTART;TZID=Eastern Standard Time:20170914T183000
DTEND;TZID=Eastern Standard Time:20170914T203000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20171201T235959;BYDAY=TH
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
```

What I did was read each line and called a string to find the specific delimiter, get the part right after it, and push it into a vector.
Here is my method to read the file:

```
void SimpleCalendar::initialize(){
    int counter = 0;
    string getLine;
    ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open("cal.ics");

if(readFile.fail()){
    throw FileException("Error! Cannot open the file.");
}

while(!readFile.eof()){
    readFile >> getLine;
    size_t summ = getLine.find("SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-ca:");
    if (summ != string::npos){
        course.push_back(getLine.substr(summ+1));
        cout << course[counter] << endl;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

What it should output is: `BIG CITY` 
instead I get this -> `SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-ca:BIG`

Comment: [why `while (!readFile.eof())` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `>>`, it only reads a single word (ending with whitespace). Use `getline()` to read the whole line.

And `find()` returns the index of the beginning of the match, not the end. You need to add the length of the string you want to skip over when you call `substr()`.

```
while (readFile.getline(getLine)) {
    size_t summ = getLine.find("SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-ca:");
    if (summ != string::npos){
        course.push_back(getLine.substr(summ + sizeof "SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-ca:"));
        cout << course[counter] << '\n';
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just want to confirm how I would get the next line, like the "LOCATION:". Would I just have to do another if statement with another delimiter?

Comment: Yes, although you might want to design something more general. Like find the first `:` or `;` on the line, get the word before that, and then use a string of `if/else if/` to test it against different prefix strings.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, beware that property values may span across multiple lines using the folding mechanism described at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.1

In other words, a long summary will be represented as

```
SUMMARY:bla bla bla...
 continuation of bla bla bla
```